# Alpine Linux - Ignoring APKINDEX : Bad file Descriptor

Tags: repository, alpine-linux, apk-tools

when I do `apk update` or `apk add ...`, gives me error below:

```
fetch http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main: Bad file descriptor 
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.5372d58d.tar.gz: Bad file descriptor
fetch http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community: Bad file descriptor
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.66c84cb4.tar.gz: Bad file descriptor
2 errors; 75 distinct packages available
```

Already changed mirrors but gives same errors.

Earlier in this installation `apk` worked with no problems.
Also I can ping the server and I can download the `APKINDEX` with `wget`.

Answer (score 3):

Solved the issue by:

```
$ rm -rf /var/cache/apk
$ mkdir /var/cache/apk
```

Comment: This is a work around but create-delete the cache directory is more like a hack. Anyone know the root cause of this..

Comment: That smells  of corrupted filesystem or disk issue. I would have downloaded on another computer and compare the sha256sum with the APKINDEX downloaded from your PC.